# Deploying to Heroku with custom domain

Tags: ruby, deployment, heroku, dns

I have run the app from from the My-app.heroku.com and it works, and I have set up the DNS between my domain but whenever I open my app from the domain I have specified, heroku says "Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying."

I've looked at the documentation a few times but I don't get it.

What step am I missing?

Comment: Have you waited for the DNS TTL to expire yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you added the custom_domain add-on?

```
heroku addons:add custom_domains
```

Then tell heroku what domain you want

```
heroku domains:add www.yoursite.com
heroku domains:add yoursite.com
```

You said you already handled the DNS steps, so once you run those commands, you should be good to go.

I believe the relevant documentation is here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: when i use the command heroku `addons:add custom_domains` is saysPlease verify your account to install this add-on
 !     For more information, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/billing
 !     Confirm now at https://heroku.com/confirm

Comment: Yatish, you have to have a credit card on file to use most (all?) addons on heroku

Comment: Is it possible to add a wildcard * ? or this will affect the heroku configuration..